# Dumping workflow persisted data?

Tags: workflow

On a large SharePoint Farm, we have several worflows designed.

Some of them are Visual Studio Workflow.

When something goes wrong in the workflow only few evidence are visible (some in the uls logs, and sometimes in the workflow history).

I would like to be able to detail what data is persisted in the workflow, in order to diagnose what's wrong.

Is there any way to dump the workflow persisted state?

I've tried using Powershell :

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://my_sp_web
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
$item = $list.Items.GetItemById(42)
$wf = $item.Workflows[0]
```

But unfortunately, my `$wf` variable does contains anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do that.

Why not add a better error handling?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419656.aspx

Best regards,

Comment: You are right. This would be the better solution. Unfortunately it's hardly applicable immediately. There is a very large code base, and each modification should be budgetised, developed, tested, etc. This won't solve my immediate issue.